# Как нормально вывести текст с тегами?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Есть текст по типу: `<p>Explore a vast, beautiful, and immersive world<br /> Explore a vast, beautiful, immersive, and dangerous world filled with gripping enemy encounters, challenging puzzles and thrilling escape sequences. Unravel Ori’s true destiny in this emotionally engaging, hand crafted story driven adventure.</p>`
Мне надо превратить это все в элементы.
Я делаю так:

```
<div>
    @Model.Description
</div>
```

Но это не работает и тескт выводится не так как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    @Html.Raw(Model.Description)
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Comment: @doomer2000 Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.